# Search asmack answerForm

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I want to search a user in my local open fire server
But after make answerForm it crashed (in try catch go to catch)

It’s my code:

```
      UserSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(connection);

        try {

            Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search.mahan-pc");
            Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
            ...


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error", "error");

        }
```

I am beginner in xmpp
can everybody help me ?

Comment: If an exception is thrown, then the thrown exception usually contains some kind of information about the cause. I suggest you look at the thrown exception. Either debug the code, log the exception, or simply `e.printStackTrace()`.